# Remove spaces from values in the array explode() returns

Tags: php, explode

I got this code that will :

1. Ask user to upload `.docx` which contains format like this (`erina`, `natasha culler`, `danial joshstone`)
2. After they upload the list name will be inserted to the database. Every name got teir own row in database.

The code below is running well. But after the name is inserted, the database becomes like this:

[image]

If you see the first name `erina`, you can see that it got a big space. But rest of the names were inserted perfectly. It's just for the first one. I dont know why. Because of that space I cant search query the erina name. I tried many things, but still got that result.

```
     <?php
    include 'configure.php';

    if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) 
    {

    $document_path = $_FILES ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
    $document_name=$_FILES ['uploaded_file']['name'];

    function extracttext($filename,$filepath) 
    {
        $ext = explode('.', $filename);
        $ext=end ($ext);
        if($ext == 'docx')
        $dataFile = "word/document.xml";
        else
        $dataFile = "content.xml";    

        $zip = new ZipArchive;

        if (true === $zip->open($filepath)) 
       {

        if (($index = $zip->locateName($dataFile)) !== false) 
        {
            $text = $zip->getFromIndex($index);

            $xml = new DOMDocument;
            $xml->loadXML($text, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);

            return strip_tags($xml->saveXML());
        }

        $zip->close();
      }
    return "File not found";
  }

    $friendslist = extracttext($document_name,$document_path);

    $id = "24";

    $friendarray = explode(",", $friendslist);
    $frienduserarray = array();

    for ($n = 0; $n < count($friendarray); $n++) 
    {
      $friendidpush = "('".$id."','".$friendarray[$n]."'),";
      array_push($frienduserarray, $friendidpush);
    }


    $query = "INSERT INTO keywords (criteria, value) VALUES ";
    $friendarray = explode(",", $friendslist);

    foreach ($friendarray as $friend) 
    {
           $query .= "('" . $id . "','" . $friend . "'),";
    }

      $query = substr($query, 0, -1); // remove trailing comma

      mysql_query($query);
}
?>
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Add this line after `$friendarray = explode(",", $friendslist);`: `$friendarray = array_map('trim', $friendarray);`.

Comment: @AmalMurali yes dear...everyone said use the trim() function.. I really forgot about trim()..so embarrassed..haha.. thank you very much dear for your reply and edited post dear.. :)

Comment: No problem, @rita. I'm not sure if you need to add the "dear" thing in all your comments. It's... not very useful. Just saying.

Comment: @AmalMurali haha..its ok..I understand..just over excited with my happy emotion.. women + over emotion = bad.. :) thanks again..case closed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `trim()` to remove whitespace before inserting

```
foreach ($friendarray as $friend) 
{
       $query .= "('" . $id . "','" . trim($friend) . "'),";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, If you want to remove to much spacing on each exploded value, you could use `array_map` then `trim`. Consider this example:

```
// this is just a sample!
$friendarray = 'friend1,              friend2, friend3, friend4';
$friendarray = explode(',', $friendarray);
$friendarray = array_map('trim', $friendarray);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($friendarray);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Using trim() will help to remove whitespace in each word.

`$query .= "('" . $id . "','" . trim($friend) . "'),";`

You can refer to the documentation of trim() function [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), for further functionality of the same.